# IBM Urbancode Deploy get current component versions deployed to an environment

Tags: ucd

I am trying get current component version of component that is deployed to an environment in UCD via REST API/Curl command . Below is sample code which returns all versions of that component which is available in UCD. It does not give me latest version of that component deployed to an environment. Any help / suggestion?

```
curl -k -u userName:passw0rd \
-H "Accept: application/json" \  
"https://myserver.example.com:8443/rest/deploy/environment/{environmentID}/versions/{componentID}"
```

Comment: I am also looking for this info but for ucd 6.2.0

Comment: The answer below works for 6.2.x

Answer (score 2):

uDeploy has a bunch of api endpoints that are undocumented. I could not figure out how to do this from their docs but inspecting the uDeploy web interface many times can help you find the endpoint to hit.

https://{your-udeploy-url}/rest/deploy/environment/{your-environment-id}/latestDesiredInventory/true?rowsPerPage=10000&pageNumber=1&orderField=name&sortType=desc

This will return json that you can parse to get the versions deployed in an environment.